# Uso de stacktable en tabla con llamado de un modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, bootstrap-4, stacktable

Saludos creo me he encontrado con un bug
estoy tratando de implementar este script para hacer [tablas responsive](https://johnpolacek.github.io/stacktable.js/)

```
<script>
     $('#usuarios').stacktable();
</script>
```

La tabla que se genera se hace de manera automática y aplica lo que debe hacer sin problemas, pero cuando intento hacer un llamado de un modal por medio de un boton la accion que se ejecuta es que se pone todo oscuro como que va a cargar el modal pero dicho modal no se carga.

La consola de chrome me da estos mensajes

```
[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking <some> event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See <URL>
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 241ms
jquery.js:3623 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 200ms
www.google.co.ve/ads…random=3861579806:1 GET https://www.google.co.ve/ads/ga-audiences?v=1&aip=1&t=sr&_r=4&tid=UA-139158…7.1559618109&jid=1119011796&_v=j77&z=1443215001&slf_rd=1&random=3861579806 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

A alguno aca le ha ocurrido esto..? sabe cómo solventarlo..?

Answer (score 1):

He solucionado efectuando una correccion en mi codigo de impresion.
Yo estaba utilizando una logica errada para imprimir mi modal yo estaba haciendo

```
$boton_modal = <button ...;
$boton_modal .= <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal...;

$accion = '<div class="btn-group-vertical" >' . $boton_modal .'</div>';
```

y he colocado ahora

```
$boton_modal = <button ...;
$variable_modal .= <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal...;

echo $variable_modal;

$accion = '<div class="btn-group-vertical" >' . $boton_modal .'</div>';
```

y me funciona perfectamente.